# My barcode reader app doesn't work. How can I run my barcode reader app?

Tags: android, barcode

I made a project with navigation tabs. When i click barcode tab it doesnt work. Can u help me to solve this error.

This is my MainApplication.class, I used switch-case structure, when i click barcode tab it doesnt work.

```
case R.id.btnbarkod:
                Intent indent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BarkodActivity.class);
                startActivity(indent);
                return true;
```

Here is my BarcodeActivity,

```
public class BarkodActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

ZXingScannerView ScannerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(ScannerView);
    ScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    String barkod = result.getText();
    Toast.makeText(this, barkod, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    ScannerView.startCamera();
}
}
```

Comment: Please specify "it doesn't work". BarcodeActivity doesn't show? The ZXingScannerView doesn't show?

Comment: yeah, doesn't show.

Comment: What doesn't show? The entire BarcodeActivity? Or just the ZXingScannerView?

Comment: i added camera permission but dont know these codes is true

Comment: when i click btnbarcode activity it is closing

Comment: Please define BarkodActivity in your manifest file. or paste your Manifest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `onCreate`, you do `setContentView(ScannerView);`, but `ScannerView` is still empty at this point: it is initialized the line below. Therefore: initialize `ScannerView` before calling `setContentView`.